# "Error saving rules – Line 1: Parse error" when I try to add this rule into firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been following [Store User Profile data in Firebase FireStore | Firestore Tutorials | Android Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watchv=RiHGwJ_u27k&list=PLlGT4GXi8_8dDK5Y3KCxuKAPpil9V49rN&index=4&ab_channel=SmallAcademy) and he added to google firebase rules in realtime database this:

```
rules_version ='2'
    service cloud.firestore {
       match /databases/{databases}/documents {
          match /{document=**} {
             allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
  }
 }
}
```

I did all the previous tutorials he did until here, but when I try to add this rule into firebase it's showing me this error Error saving rules – Line 1: Parse error and I didn't found anything about this. I am new in programming and a beginner in google firebase.

Comment: What you've shown are rules for Cloud Firestore, and the tutorial also seems to be for that. Are you sure you're not trying to use those rules on the Realtime Database? While both databases are part of Firebase, they are completely separate, and the rules for one don't work on the other.

Comment: I am trying to add those rules in Realtime Database -> Rules, but it gives me this error : Error saving rules – Line 1: Parse error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security rules you're showing apply to Cloud Firestore, but you're trying to add them to the Realtime Database. While both databases are part of Firebase, they're completely separate, and the security rules for one don't apply to the other.

To fix the error, you will have to set the same rules in the correct place by clicking Firestore in the Firebase console.